# Conditional rendering with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

**The context :**
I try to build a form with hooks and render component depending on the step we are.

**Problem :**
I have this message : "Error: UserFormHooks(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

I know the code work with class but no with hooks.

**What I tried :** I tried to put them in a ternary but it doesn't work either.

**Code :**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormUserDetails from "./FormUserDetails";
import FormPersonalDetails from "./FormPersonalDetails";
import Confirm from "./Confirm";
import Success from "./Success";

const UserFormHooks = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    step: 1,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    occupation: "",
    city: "",
    bio: "",
  });

  // Proceed to next step
  const nextStep = () => {
    setData(step + 1);
  };

  // Go back to prev step
  const prevStep = () => {
    setData(step - 1);
  };

  // Handle fields change
  const handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
    setData({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  const { step } = { data };
  const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio } = { data };
  const values = { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio };

  switch (step) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <FormUserDetails
            nextStep={nextStep}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        </div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <div>
          <FormPersonalDetails
            nextStep={nextStep}
            prevStep={prevStep}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        </div>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <Confirm nextStep={nextStep} prevStep={prevStep} values={values} />
      );
    case 4:
      return <Success />;
    default:
      console.log("This is a multi-step form built with React.");
  }
};

export default UserFormHooks;
```

Comment: Disregarding your main problem for a second, state in hooks doesn't work like that. You either need a separate line like `const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState("");` for each state variable, or create a full copy of `data`, change the one field, then call `setData(changedCopyOfData)`;

Comment: Also, deconstruction assignments work like `const { step } = data;`, what you have there is equivalent to `const { step } = { data: data };`, which has an object on the right side that doesn't have a `step` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix following problems in your code:

1. `setData()` will overwrite the existing state instead merging the new state with the previous state. So, make sure you pass the previous state as well when calling `setData()`

   ```
   setData({ ...data, step: step + 1 });
   ```
2. You are not destructuring correctly. You are creating a new object with `data` property which leads to `step` being `undefined` and hence `default` case of `switch` statement executes. Since you are not returning anything from `default` case, an error is thrown because you must always return something from your component.

   ```
   const { step } = data;
   const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio } = data;
   ```
3. make sure you return something from the `default` case of `switch` statement

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggests, you need to return JSX from a component. Alternatively you need to return `null` if no JSX is returned:

```
default:
   console.log("This is a multi-step form built with React.");
   return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the default state with `setData(step + 1)` This will set the state to a single number instead of updating the step value inside the object you specified inside `useState`.

To update the state and keep the current properties you can use the `prevState` with the `setState`.

`prevState` like the name suggests holds the previous state which in your case is the object from `useState`.

```
setData((prevState) => ({
 ...prevState,
 step: prevState.step + 1,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use updater function when use `setData`

```js
setData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }));
```

Hooks with objects works differently, compared to normal `setState` in Component Class